# Are there any static code analysis tools for Delphi/Pascal?

Tags: delphi, static-analysis, pascal

Are there any static code analysis tools for Delphi/Pascal?

I have seen plenty of options for C++ and .NET, but nothing for Delphi/Pascal.

Ideally something that could be integrated into a continuous integration system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/) is nice.

Answer (score 17):

If you want something that will give you various software metrics (complexity etc.) for your code then I strongly recommend SourceMonitor from [Campswood Software](http://www.campwoodsw.com). It works for C and C++ too, and it's free.

Comment: This is a great tool. very cool graphs.

Answer (score 16):

The Architect version of Delphi has a very powerful Audits and Metrics feature that does a complete analysis of your code.  The feature provides a complete analysis of your source code.  A very under appreciated feature, I think.

Comment: Is it somewhat mimicable in D5 + Jenkins + XUnit cooperation?

Comment: The Delphi Audit and Metrics are definitely useful by detecting not only coding rules violation, but also by **detecting architecture smells** . The results on my projects were very very interesting. This is surely the kind of unknown Delphi feature I think !

Comment: I've been using the Audits and metrics in Delphi XE2, and have found them a little broken (only been able to scan about 20% of a large project) - still very useful however and would certainly recommend them.

Comment: In XE2 they are very broken for me, giving wrong results and sometimes getting the line number wrong. Sad, because this tool would've been such a boon.

Answer (score 9):

[CodeHealer](http://www.socksoftware.com/codehealer.php) does source code analysis and verification

A version came with BDS2006, But the number of visibility hints is limited to 4 per category.
[have a look at this link](http://www.socksoftware.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=255)

It works well on a small project but this limitation makes it very hard if not impossible to use on a large project.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't a demo.  It was a fully working copy.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new [FixInsight](http://sourceoddity.com/fixinsight/) tool which does source code analysis and verification.

Answer (score 4):

[Pascal Analyser](http://www.peganza.com/), Delphi 2006+ has built in audits and metrics, [Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/) and [Code Healer](http://www.socksoftware.com/codehealer.php) are the ones that I'm aware of - all are pretty useful.

Comment: For everybody reading later ; the full Audits and Metrics feature is found only in Delphi ARCHITECT SKUs only.  Although I believe a very limited subset of audits and metrics were introduced in Delphi/RAD 2010 even in the Pro SKU.

Answer (score 2):

On Sourceforge there is a project [Delphi Code Analyzer DCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dca/) with quite many downloads and last activity in 2009, maybe interesting

Answer (score 0):

AQTime from AutomatedQA offers a Static Analysis Profiler. I have never used this profiler but am happy with those AQTime profilers that I use regularly. If you go down this path you can integrate AQTime with TestComplete to accomplish this sort of profiling as part of a continuous integration approach.