# FxCop/StyleCop for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, fxcop, stylecop

Does anyone know of an equivalent to FxCop/StyleCop for Delphi? I would really like to get the automatic checking of style, etc. into Continuous Integration.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532986/are-there-any-static-code-analysis-tools-for-delphi-pascal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest I've seen is [CodeHealer from SOCK software](http://www.socksoftware.com/codehealer.php). We use it, and we have integrated it into our FinalBuilder build. It differs from FxCop in one important way: It analyzes the source code, rather than the produced executable. It also doesn't check quite as much as FxCop does. But I think it is the best thing which is available in this category for Delphi.

Delphi 2009 support isn't there just yet, but they say they're working on it.

Comment: I've just tried CodeHealer, and whilst it looks OK, it doesn't support D2009, so this is a non-starter at the moment unfortunately

Comment: Codehealer 2.6 (released 2009-10-20) includes support for Delphi 2009 and 2010 according to their web site

Comment: @mjustin Just in time for Delphi XE :)

Comment: **CodeHealer 2.8 for Delphi XE1 now in beta testing** - according to the Code Healer Group Home Page :)

Answer (score 12):

There's Pascal Analyzer from Peganza: http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.htm

I don't know how the features compare to FxCop, since I haven't really used either one.

Answer (score 2):

[Delphi Code Analyzer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dca/) is another one that is open source.

Answer (score 1):

The [DGrok](http://dgrok.excastle.com/) project started with something like FxCop some years ago. The parser and analysis parts are still available, read more at "[DGrok 0.8.1: multithreading, default options, GPL](http://blog.excastle.com/2008/09/14/dgrok-081-multithreading-default-options-gpl/)" - The parser is a .Net project but

> DGrok is a set of tools for parsing
>   Delphi source code and telling you
>   stuff about it. Read more about it on
>   the DGrok project page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [Delphi plugin for Sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Delphi+Plugin), which uses a Delphi grammar to run automatic tests over the source code.

Comment: Yes - I now use this, actually is great and I would recommend it highly

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of something called [Delforex](http://www.delphipages.com/result.cfm?ID=629) but haven't used it myself (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Delforex is great for actually formatting the code.  It does not do much more than that though.  (we have/do use it).

I would second the votes for either Pascal Analyzer or Code Healer.

Vaccano

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Delphi output .net compatible IL code? I haven't used it in an age but I thought newer versions output .net assemblies.

If so then I would have thought FXcop would work and you could always add some of your own custom rules to it.  Stylecop would not work but you could at least get FXCop running.

Comment: Delphi 2009 is native win32. In this case this is unfortunate

Comment: Codehealer 2.6 now supports Delphi 2009 and 2010.