# Coding style tool for Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, coding-style, delphi-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FxCop / StyleCop for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808961/fxcop-stylecop-for-delphi)

Hi !
Has anyone encountered with some coding style tool like StyleCop, but for Delphi 2010 ?
I would appreciate if someone recommends any free tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808961/fxcop-stylecop-for-delphi

Answer (score 1):

[Delphi Code Analyzer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dca/) is one.

Comment: +1; Maybe you can add that answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808961/fxcop-stylecop-for-delphi as well?