# Code Analysis tool for Delphi 4

Tags: delphi, code-analysis

I need a **Code analysis tool** that supports Delphi 4.

I tried some of the following Tools:

1. Code healer (Supports from Delphi 5)
2. Pascal analyzer

Could you please say which will be the best tool for analyzing **Delphi 4** code files.

Comment: Something similar to FxCop.User friendly and reliable to use

Comment: What do except from analysis tool? What it should tell you?

Answer (score 4):

Pascal Analyzer has support for all Delphi versions except the latest one, from it's FAQ page:

> Which versions are supported by Pascal Analyzer?
>
> ```
> * Borland Pascal 7 (or earlier)
> * Delphi 1
> * Delphi 2
> * Delphi 3
> * Delphi 4
> * Delphi 5
> * Delphi 6
> * Delphi 7
> * Delphi 8 .NET
> * Delphi 2005 Win32
> * Delphi 2005 .NET
> * Delphi 2006 Win32 (also Turbo Delphi for Win32)
> * Delphi 2006 .NET    (also Turbo Delphi for .NET)
> * Delphi 2007 Win32
> * Delphi 2007 .NET
> ```

**EDIT**: refer to this [question for other Analysis tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532986/are-there-any-static-code-analysis-tools-for-delphi-pascal)

Also defining the best is some rely on your code and situation, to choose the best, you have to download each one and decide if it fits your needs or not.

Comment: Thanks for your Response.
Yes pascal analzyer supports delphi 4. I want to know whether it is the best one or any other tool will support delphi 4

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be [Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/) or you could update to a new version of Delphi which has static code analysis.  I would certainly recommend trying them all out, particularly Pascal Analyser & Source Monitor as they are free.