# Analyze Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, code-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any static code analysis tools for Delphi/Pascal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532986/are-there-any-static-code-analysis-tools-for-delphi-pascal)

Is there any tool that will help me analyze my Delphi code? Like giving me lists of non-used identifiers, call graphs, warnings about bad code etcetera?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532986/are-there-any-static-code-analysis-tools-for-delphi-pascal. Also, the newer Delphi versions (I think from D2010 onwards) have static analysis built into them, though what's available may depend on the incarnation (Pro, Enterprise or Architect).

Comment: Pascal Analyzer from Peganza. Ergo I voted to close as exact dupe.