# Which program analysis tools for Delphi support continuous integration systems?

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, static-analysis

Which [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) or [dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis) [program analysis tools for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532986/are-there-any-static-code-analysis-tools-for-delphi-pascal) provide integration with [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (CI) software?

For example these (open source and commercial) CI systems:

- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)/[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)
- [Atlassian Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview)
- [JetBrains TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
- [VSoft FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/)
- [Smartbear Automated Build Studio](http://smartbear.com/products/software-development/software-release-management)

(If the program analysis tools provide output in a format which can be used by the CI report generation subsystem, this would be helpful to know too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These code analysis tools for Delphi have CI support:

- [Sonar plugin for Delphi](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Delphi+Plugin): integration with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)/[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (including reports)
- [Delphi Code Coverage](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/): integration with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)/[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (including EMMA report integration)